# What is basic things to write a blog?

Tags: blog

HI.. I need to create my own blog. For that what are the basic steps i need to take care. 
I am good in .net. I like to share my knowledge.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, decide whether you want to create your own blogging software or use someone elses.

Then decide whether you want to host it yourself or not.

I'm not sure about .NET blogging tools, but [wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org) is a firm favourite. If you want someone else to host it, take a look at [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com) or [Posterous](http://www.posterous.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'm not sure why you want to reinvent the wheel here. There are plenty of easy-to-use free blogging services. I'll third WordPress for ease and customizability.

Answer (score 0):

As .NET is usually the preserve of companies and individuals who don't want to share their code, finding a free .NET blogging platform will prove difficult.

That said, if you are good with .NET then you should find it fairly easy to build a blog platform for .NET. I'm learning .NET as part of my job, and I don't think it's all that difficult to do.

That said, I would go for WordPress. Regardless of what background you have with programming, WordPress is easy to set up and maintain as you don't need to know specific coding languages to make it work.

Comment: What: "don't need to know specific coding languages" If you never intend to touch your templates, I suppose. Otherwise, yes you do: PHP.

Comment: Your right, if you need to interfere with the templates you will need to know PHP (in relation to WordPress). But the beauty of WordPress is that people with minimal knowledge of PHP can make a CMS system.